# How to play an audio when a button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I am having problems with setting up a button that will play audio when pressed.
I am using `tkinter` for the button and `simpleaudio` for the audio.

```
x = ""
def audio(file):
    x = file
    return x
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Audio")
audio_button = tk.Button(window,text="Audio Test",command=audio("imposter")).pack(side="left")
audio_button1 = tk.Button(window,text="Audio Test Two",command=audio("crewmate")).pack(side="left")
stop_all = tk.Button(window,text="Stop All",command=audio("stop"),fg="red").pack(side="left")
tk.mainloop()
while True:
    if not x == "stop":
        if x == "crewmate":
            wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("File here")
            play_obj = wave_obj.play()
            while play_obj.is_playing():
                if x == "stop":
                    break
                else:
                pass
        elif x == "imposter":
            wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file("File here")
            play_obj = wave_obj.play()
            while play_obj.is_playing():
                if x == "stop":
                    break
                else:
                    pass
    else:
        pass
```

And it would be nice to help shorten the code a bit too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pack` returns None, therefore you should chain pack to the creation of a widget when you need to keep a reference to the widget.

Here is a possible approach to your problem; I do not have simple audio, so I cannot guarantee the code is fully correct; the code lines with `simpleaudio` calls are commented out, and print statements allow you to verify the logic. You will have to un-comment them, and try.

The logic stops all audio before launching a new file; you may want to make it a bit more user friendly, like letting the song finish if the command requests the same song, instead of restarting it.

```
# import simpleaudio as sa
import tkinter as tk

def stop_audio():
    print('stopping all')
#   sa.stopall()

def test_audio(state):
    if state == 'imposter':
        path = "path/to/imposter.wav"
    elif state == 'crewmate':
        path = "path/to/crewmate.wav"
    else:
        return
#     wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(path)
    stop_audio()
#     play_obj = wave_obj.play()
    print(f'playing {state}')
    
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Audio")

audio_button = tk.Button(window,text="Audio Test", command=lambda state='imposter': test_audio(state))
audio_button.pack(side="left")

audio_button1 = tk.Button(window,text="Audio Test Two", command=lambda state='crewmate': test_audio(state))
audio_button1.pack(side="left")

stop_all = tk.Button(window,text="Stop All",fg="red", command=stop_audio)
stop_all.pack(side="left")

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's really helpful since I'm preparing an audio program for Halloween.